# How to perform a "grouped merge" of three files, while omitting the first few lines of each?

Tags: text-processing, awk, merge

This is my reproducible example

- `file01.txt`

  ```
  line to skip
  line to skip
  line to skip
  line to keep file 01
  heading 1 in the form: 2017243 01 2017243 01
  data 1 file 01
  heading 2 in the form: 2017243 02 2017243 02
  data 2 file 01
  heading 3 in the form: 2017243 03 2017243 03
  data 3 file 01
  ```
- `file02.txt`

  ```
  line to skip
  line to skip
  line to skip
  line to keep file 02
  heading 1 in the form: 2017243 01 2017243 01
  data 1 file 02
  heading 2 in the form: 2017243 02 2017243 02
  data 2 file 02
  heading 3 in the form: 2017243 03 2017243 03
  data 3 file 02
  ```
- `file03.txt`

  ```
  line to skip
  line to skip
  line to skip
  line to keep file 03
  heading 1 in the form: 2017243 01 2017243 01
  data 1 file 03
  heading 2 in the form: 2017243 02 2017243 02
  data 2 file 03
  heading 3 in the form: 2017243 03 2017243 03
  data 3 file 03
  ```
- desired output

  ```
  line to keep file 01
  line to keep file 02
  line to keep file 03
  heading 1 in the form: 2017243 01 2017243 01
  data 1 file 01
  data 1 file 02
  data 1 file 03
  heading 2 in the form: 2017243 02 2017243 02
  data 2 file 01
  data 2 file 02
  data 2 file 03
  heading 3 in the form: 2017243 03 2017243 03
  data 3 file 01
  data 3 file 02
  data 3 file 03
  ```

So far I've managed the pretty simple task to extract the fourth lines from each input file by:

```
awk 'FNR == 4' *.txt >> out_row4
```

but then I got stuck with the rest of the file processing and can not conceive a viable final solution...

I need to keep the solution quite general because the number of files and the rows to be processed are quite large (more than 5900 rows per file)

General pattern to keep as reference:

- always skip the first 3 lines for each file
- keep the 4th row for each file
- the headings 1, 2, 3 (... and so on) are exactly the same across different files (so they need to be reported just once in the desired output file)
- all files contain the same number of lines
- files do not have a known structured format, they are plain text files

the common pattern to be extracted and rearranged is:

```
heading n in the form: 2017243 n 2017243 n
data n file ...
```

any hint for that?

Comment: Unfortunately, your question still lacks details. While your effort to provide a testable example is commendable, you may still want to provide some explanation of the task. How do you determine how many lines to skip? Is it always the first three? How is the data grouping determined? Are there always the same headers in all 3 input files? Is the number of data lines always the same? Please edit your question to include these informations.

Comment: The question isn't clear to me, do you need to ignore the first 3 rows from each file and then order them taking one line from each file?

Comment: thank you for the reply, I've edited the question

Comment: Are the input files on a known structured format, such as YAML, CSV, XML, etc.?

Comment: not known structured format, plain text files

Comment: You're getting some answers that are only producing the expected output because your sample input a) will coincidentally sort in the desired output order, and b) doesn't contain duplicate lines between files. You should change `data 1 file 01` and `data 1 file 03` both to `foobar` to solve both problems with the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applying the [DSU Idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71691113/how-to-sort-data-based-on-the-value-of-a-column-for-part-multiple-lines-of-a-f/71694367#71694367), using any versions of the mandatory POSIX tools awk, sort, and cut:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

awk -v OFS='\t' '
    FNR == 1 { fileNr++ }
    FNR >= 4 { print FNR-3, fileNr, $0 }
' "${@:--}" |
sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2 |
awk '($1 % 2) || ($2 == 1)' |
cut -f 3-
```

```
$  ./tst.sh file01.txt file02.txt file03.txt
line to keep file 01
line to keep file 02
line to keep file 03
heading 1 in the form: 2017243 01 2017243 01
data 1 file 01
data 1 file 02
data 1 file 03
heading 2 in the form: 2017243 02 2017243 02
data 2 file 01
data 2 file 02
data 2 file 03
heading 3 in the form: 2017243 03 2017243 03
data 3 file 01
data 3 file 02
data 3 file 03
```

The only tool above that has to handle all of the input at once is `sort` which is designed to handle huge amounts of input by using demand paging, etc. and so is likely to succeed no matter how many input files you have (as long as they don't exceed ARG_MAX of course) or how large they are.

Alternatively, using any awk and assuming the number of input files isn't large enough to produce a "too many open files" error:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    while ( ! eof ) {
        for ( fileNr=1; fileNr<ARGC; fileNr++ ) {
            if ( (getline vals[fileNr] < ARGV[fileNr]) <= 0 ) {
                eof = 1
            }
        }
        if ( !eof && (++lineNr >= 4) ) {
            if ( lineNr % 2 ) {
                print vals[1]
            }
            else {
                for ( fileNr=1; fileNr<ARGC; fileNr++ ) {
                    print vals[fileNr]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    exit
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file01.txt file02.txt file03.txt
line to keep file 01
line to keep file 02
line to keep file 03
heading 1 in the form: 2017243 01 2017243 01
data 1 file 01
data 1 file 02
data 1 file 03
heading 2 in the form: 2017243 02 2017243 02
data 2 file 01
data 2 file 02
data 2 file 03
heading 3 in the form: 2017243 03 2017243 03
data 3 file 01
data 3 file 02
data 3 file 03
```

I'm using `getline` cautiously above to avoid reading most of your input files into memory at once, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for more info on when/how to use it.

Comment: plenty l to study and learn about from your thorough answer, thanks

Comment: Ed, I've been carefully looking so far just the first approach you proposed, and it's great no doubt! There is just one thing I do not grasp yet: what is the purpose and why the need of the use "$@" after the first call of awk; is that for checking any parameters passed by the user? and why of that? the script seems to work properly also by omitting that part...

Comment: That's the shell syntax to access all of the arguments passed to a shell script, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/9994295/1745001. If you call a shell script as `script foo bar` then inside the script `"$@"` expands to `"foo" "bar"`. I just changed it from `"$@"` to `"${@:--}"` though so it can handle input coming from a pipe or from a list of files just for more flexibility. "${@:--}"` means "use the list of arguments (`$@)` if present, otherwise (`:-`) use stdin (the final `-`)".

Answer (score 0):

i did save the patterns you gave above in three files. I got the desired output completting your awk-filtering on this way:

```
for i in {4..15}; do awk "FNR == $i" *.txt | sort -u; done
```

Comment: wow, that's pretty close to what I need: so clean and terse! Is there a way to generalise the code to any unknown in advance  number of rows (which are in the original files clearly more than 15, as per your example code)?  I'm here thinking to use a BEGIN construct to count the number of rows in the file (any file) to be passed later in the 'for loop' sequence {4..NR}; clearly,  with an hacking approach, I can keep the final number of rows 'big enough' to scan all the content of the files but the ideal solution would be to pass the exact number of rows...

Comment: for me this is the most cleaner approach (it's in fact the one I prefer) but I still need to work on that in order to sort out the issue about passing the total number of rows to be processed... I'll post any update on that, thank you

Comment: That's only producing the desired output because of the specific values in the posted sample input just happening to sort in the desired order and not contain duplicate values across files, it'd fail given various other input values.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using something else other than awk:

`for f in $(ls *.txt) ; do awk 'FNR >=4' $f | egrep "." -n ; done  | sort -n | uniq | cut -d: -f2-`

would do the trick

explanation:

- the for loop will remove the first 3 line from each file (using awk) and numerate them (using egrep -n with any char as condition to grep)
- then will sort the outputs by line number
- then will remove the duplicated heading lines
- finally will remove the line number

**UPDATE**:

I removed egrep usage since awk were already going through the whole file it can also add the line number to the output (avoids reading the file 2 times).

`for f in $(ls *.txt) ; do awk 'FNR >=4 {printf("%s#%s\n", FNR-3, $0)}' $f ; done | sort -n | uniq | cut -d# -f2-`

Comment: yup! that's great! with a small change to fit my needs:

`for f in $(ls *.txt) ; do awk 'FNR >=4' $f | egrep "." -n ; done  | sort -n | uniq | cut -d: -f2- `

Comment: sorry but I do not get exactly your point about the separator character, which can also be handled directly by awk though the built in variable FS; your update seems to me now a more complicated solution even if working properly,,,

Comment: I removed the part that was confusing you. The updated solution improves performance. Since you mentioned files with a lot of rows and the old solution went through all the rows 2 times, this one enumerate them while it removes the first 3 so its faster/more efficient

Comment: I see now, I'm here pointing that at the end there is a minus sign not strictly necessary, I think...

 `for f in $(ls *.txt) ; do awk 'FNR >=4 {printf("%s#%s\n", FNR-3, $0)}' $f ; done | sort -n | uniq | cut -d# -f2`

thank you, a good solution

Comment: That would fail if 2 lines from 2 files had the same content, e.g. if line 5 in both file1 and file2 was `foobar`, and the `sort` can/will produce output in a different order to the input so line 5 of file 3 could be output before line 5 of file1, depending on the content of those lines (you're getting the expected order now just by coincidence based on the sample data values). Also, `for f in $(ls *.txt)` would be an anti-pattern, see mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs, and `sort -n | uniq = sort -nu`.